# Junit initialize() vs setUp() Java

Tags: java, junit

I am starting with JUnit and java for Test Driven Development.
In the book I'm reading I have the following sample:

```
protected void setUp() throws Exception
{
    controller = new DefaultController();
}
```

But in the provided code of the examples I have this, not corresponding code:

```
@Before
public void initialize() throws Exception
{
    controller = new DefaultController();
}
```

What's the difference??Regards

Comment: Or maybe there's an code that I downloaded may be incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that the book was not reedited but the code was updated.

The  `void setUp()` method is a hook lifecycle method specific to JUnit 3.
From JUnit 4, an annotation is used `@Before` instead of  naming convention.
So the method is named `initialize()` but it doesn't matter.  The single thing that matters is the annotation on.

This is right for this hook but for also other hooks : `@After`, `@BeforeClass`, `@AfterClass` and so for...

Note that JUnit 5 is released. You could use it to start learning JUnit.